# select data From database in php sort by last enter first select

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to fetch data from the database, and sort by last enter and first fetch.

Its means suppose I enter

Third time I add :- **hari**

Second time I add :- **nikh22**

First time I add :- **234ram**

Now I want to fetch data sort by last enter first select

hari

nikhil22

234ram

By default it is selecting data by name, please tell me what to do

For selecting data I used

```
mysql_query ("select * from Nikhil where userid='$pid'");
```

Comment: you want to sort the data based on what row is last added?

Comment: @Nikhilgarg - what is the table structure? We can't answer this unless we know that.

Comment: add an auto-increment column as primary key for your table

Answer (score 1):

If you were to have a datetime or timestamp column in your `nikhil` table then you can order by that column in descending order

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM nikhil
 WHERE userid = ?
 ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e1ae3/1)** demo

Comment: should i need to add date time manually in this column or it will take automatically

Comment: You can use `NOW()` function to add a time of entry

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but i would like to add date not time because time will repeat. I will use date(), hope it is ok.

Comment: You're welcome. Of course you can use any appropriate data type.

Answer (score 0):

you can use datetime or timestamp just add a column in your db table